# How far can trade convoys and trade vessels travel?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

What is the maximum travel distance for trade convoys and trade vessels? In Civ 5, there was a limited number of tiles they could travel, but I don't see anything to indicate a limit in Beyond Earth. I know that there must be a path of tiles without any miasma in order for a route to be valid, but it seems that may be the only limitation.

Is there a hidden value, (that possibly scales with number of turns?) or is it simply unlimited, given there is a valid route to the destination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the in-game help on Trade Routes (emphasis mine):

> [A colony is limited in the total number of trade routes it can establish, **trade routes have unlimited range**, and the amount a specific route generates is dependent upon the diversity of resources in the two cities.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs7dn.png)

So the only restriction seems to be that there is a valid route between the two trading locations, where a valid route is an uncovered path uninterrupted by miasma, or one with miasma provided you've researched the Alien Hybridization technology, as its immunity to miasma damage applies to trade units as well:

[image: trade unit with Alien Hybridization technology going through miasma tiles]

Comment: Do you mean Alien Biology? You're talking about the tech that gives workers miasma immunity, correct? I didn't know that applied to trade routes, too; that's awesome!

Comment: Alien Biology applies the perk to Worker units, but Alien Hybridization applies it to all units (and gives them +10 Healing in miasma). I'm not 100% sure which applies to the trade routes, but I think it's Hybridization, if only because it's a lot further down the tech tree (Transgenics leaf)

Comment: AH, I see it now. I was not aware that existed, as I have not yet researched that. (But now that I know it's there, I'll likely beeline for it in my next/first Harmony game!) :D

Comment: Alien Biology is only workers, not trade routes.